# n.median() returns a 1d scalar for an array of depth 3?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array. Each cell/element in the array contains a scalar/tuple representing an RGB colour. When I attempt to calculate the `numpy.median()` or `numpy.average()` on the array I get back a 1d scalar when I should be getting back a 3d scalar/tuple.

For example;

```
f = (1,2,3)
a = np.array([[f,f,f],
    [f,f,f]])
print("A: {}, {}".format(np.median(a), a.shape))
```

Output is:

> A: 2.0, (2, 3, 3)

Shouldn't the median value be `(1,2,3)` not `2.0`?

Comment: Use with `axis` param?

Comment: @Divakar if I use the axis param, wont that compute the median for only *one* axis though? I want to compute for both axis.

Comment: You don't read doc strings, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `np.median(a, (0,1))` to calculate the median along the first two axes.